# c++ String to uint8_t

Tags: c++, string, casting

I have downloaded an image and it is saved in a `std::string`.
Now I want to use/open it with following conditions:

```
typedef uint8_t byte //1 byte unsigned integer type.  
static open(const byte * data, long size)
```

How do I cast from `string` to `byte*` ?

/EDIT:
i have already tried this:

```
_data = std::vector<byte>(s.begin(), s.end()); 
//_data = std::vector<uint8_t>(s.begin(), s.end());  //also fails, same error
_p = &_data[0];
open(_p, _data.size())
```

but i get:
undefined reference to 'open(unsigned char const*, long)'
why does it interpret byte wrongly as char?!

/EDIT2:
just to test it i changed to function call to

```
 open(*_p, _data.size())
```

but then i get:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'open(unsigned char&, size_t)'
[...] open(const byte*, long int) <near match>
```

So the function is definitly found...

Comment: Have you even checked a reference of the `string` class? If you look at e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you will quickly see _two_ functions to help you with your problem.

Comment: Why did you store the image data in a `std::string`? Strings store one thing, and one thing only: **text**. You should use a different class (namely, a byte vector).

Comment: Ah now I see you have stored binary data in the string... This is as the previous commenter said not advisable. The reason being that the binary image data can contain the value 0, which is the same value used to terminate strings. So putting it in a string will most likely give you a very small part of the image, at best.

Comment: @Joachim: "the value 0, which is the same value used to terminate strings". C++ `std::string` can safely contain zeros. You would only get truncation if you then use `c_str()` or similar to treat that data as a C-style nul-terminated string. I sort of agree that `string` is the wrong type for binary data, but that's only because of what it implies to readers. There's no functional problem with it. Note that in C++ `char` is valid to inspect any object in memory, so unlike C, C++ guarantees no issues with representing all bit-patterns.

Comment: Don't use `uint8_t` unless you **really** mean it. Use `uint_least8_t` or `uint_fast8_t`. They have the advantage of being required to exist, unlike `uint8_t`, which is optional.

Comment: And if you really mean exactly 8 bits, call it `octet`, not `byte` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1) the common one. On your system, `char` is either 2's complement or else unsigned, and hence it is "safe" to read chars as unsigned chars, and (if `char` is signed) the result is the same as converting from signed to unsigned.

In which case, use `reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(string.data())`.

2) the uncommon one. On your system, `char` is signed and not 2's complement and hence for `char *ptr` pointing to a negative value the result of `*(uint8_t*)ptr` is not equal to `(uint8_t)(*ptr)`. Then depending what `open` actually does with the data, the above might be fine or you might have to copy the data out of a string and into a container of `uint8_t`, converting as you go. For example, `vector<uint8_t> v(string.begin(), string.end());`. Then use `&v[0]` *provided that the length is not 0* (unlike string, you aren't permitted to take a pointer to the data of an empty vector even if you never dereference it).

Non-2's-complement systems are approximately non-existent, and even if there was one I think it's fairly unlikely that a system on which `char` was signed and not 2's complement would provide `uint8_t` at all (because if it does then it must also provide `int8_t`). So (2) only serves pedantic completeness.

> why does it interpret byte wrongly as char

It isn't wrong, `uint8_t` is a typedef for `unsigned char` on your system.

Comment: @Benjamin: I am one of those pedants, although I wouldn't downvote for such an omission. I might comment.

Comment: @Alex: then the problem is something else, probably you haven't linked against the object file containing the `open` function.

Comment: @Alex: "undefined reference" means that the compiler has found a declaration of the function, but the linker has not found a definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string string_with_image;

string_with_image.data();
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you're true. I mistyped that. Thanks for correction